# How can I backup my Google Drive files using Time Machine?

Tags: google-drive, osx

I'd like to be able to do regular backups of my files in Google Drive.
I just want to create a backup so that I can quickly restore in the event of a disaster.
I don't believe that Google currently offers this service.

If possible, I'd like to just integrate it into the Time Machine backup that I already do on my Mac so that I can have a copy of my Google Docs on my external hard drive updated at least once a day.

Problem seems to be that Time Machine only does backups of your system drive.
Perhaps there is a way to fool Time Machine into thinking that Google Drive is a part of my hard drive?

I thought about using Google Takeout to download the files to my local hard drive before doing a backup.
But that option requires me to download everything rather than just the files that have changed since my last download.

It also requires me to change the format of my Google Docs to something like Microsoft Word.
I'd rather not do that because the restore process would be slow and I'd probably lose a lot of the formatting in the process.

I'm okay with doing some scripting.

Anyone have an elegant solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about how to do a backup by using software included in OSX.